# Setting HardCoded Content-Length Header Causes Socket-Hangup Nginx Server ExpressJS App

Tags: express, nginx, request, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been moved my server from IIS to Linux Nginx server. Content-Length header set to 366 from another developer and loaded run on a hardware which distributed around the country. IIS server was allowing hardcoded Content-Length header although there is no content on payload. On the other hand linux nginx server doesnt allow it, and requests end up with 'Error: socket hang up'. How can I allow hardcoded content-length to rescue other developer collecting all devices and reboot with new code?

nginx.conf;

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    gzip on;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        #listen       443 ssl default_server;
        #listen       [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
           location = /50x.html {
        }
    }


server {

    server_name  xx.xx.com;
 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/xx.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/xx.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        #proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;


    }








    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.xx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.xx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = xx.xx.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   server_name  xx.xx.com;
    listen 80;
  
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}}
```